# Network manager crashing in 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, services

I just finished a Ubuntu 14.04 install and everything was going fine until the network started dropping in and out. I have checked the router -the windows machine has no issues- the network card and a pretty much everything else I could rule out over the last three days. Then I saw that there was an issue with a bug getting into an update 8 months ago that was causing the network manager to crash.

After doing more research I have confirmed that my card is working, the system is seeing the card, and that the connection settings are correct and stable. I can also see the network manager shut down in my system logs and when the connection is lost I can restart it immediately if I do it manually at the command line but it won't restart on its own.

Several pages I've come across have said that the bug that was causing the manager to crash had been solved and released but I am having an almost identical problem.

Does anyone know if the bug that was causing the manager to crash is fixed or if it's still causing issues?

It's been a long and tough install process and I just want to put the last nail in the coffin. everything else works fine.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and reboot and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks. I had done all except the dist-upgrade before posting. Having run all three commands in sequence yields me"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Answer (score 0):

I got this today out of the system logs when the connection dropped again. I don't know it this helps. I have some experience with linux but I am moving from a windows environment so a lot of this is foreign to me.

```
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'removed') [36]
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1662
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.143 on eth0.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.143.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    dnsmasq[1668]   setting upstream servers from DBus
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> (eth0): cleaning up...
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> (eth0): taking down device.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address 2601:445:4101:3bab:3cb5:9f3a:bd76:2edf.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Withdrawing address record for 2601:445:4101:3bab:feaa:14ff:fe93:38c5 on eth0.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    avahi-daemon[706]   Withdrawing address record for 2601:445:4101:3bab:3cb5:9f3a:bd76:2edf on eth0.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    dbus[510]   [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    dnsmasq[1668]   exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[920] <info> exiting (success)
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    dbus[510]   [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.8.8) is starting...
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> Read config file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> WEXT support is enabled
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> DNS: loaded plugin dnsmasq
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]         interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]         interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0): no ifupdown configuration found.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]   <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ofono: Acquired D-Bus service com.canonical.NMOfono
01/16/17 09:53:11 AM    studionBitch    NetworkManager[11906]      SCPlugin-Ofono: init!
```

I'm also getting something from a process called whoopsie[1207] that simply states offline.

I also just got this from the kernal.

```
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526431] ------------[ cut here ]------------
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526445] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 3 at /build/linux-jxap_Z/linux-3.13.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:264 dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280()
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526450] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526453] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy pci_stub vboxpci(OX) vboxnetadp(OX) vboxnetflt(OX) vboxdrv(OX) cuse dm_crypt joydev snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_holtek_kbd kvm_amd kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core snd_usb_audio videodev snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi rfcomm snd_pcm bnep bluetooth snd_seq serio_raw k10temp fam15h_power edac_core edac_mce_amd snd_page_alloc fglrx(POX) i2c_piix4 snd_seq_device snd_timer binfmt_misc snd amd_iommu_v2 soundcore shpchp parport_pc ppdev mac_hid lp parport pata_acpi hid_generic psmouse usbhid usb_storage hid ahci r8169 pata_atiixp libahci mii
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526543] CPU: 0 PID: 3 Comm: ksoftirqd/0 Tainted: P           OX 3.13.0-107-lowlatency #154-Ubuntu
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526547] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./970A-UD3P, BIOS FA 10/28/2014
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526551]  0000000000000000 ffff8802331a1c88 ffffffff81731833 ffff8802331a1cd0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526558]  0000000000000009 ffff8802331a1cc0 ffffffff8106b97d 0000000000000000
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526564]  ffff88022d6a8000 ffff88022d8d6e80 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526571] Call Trace:
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526580]  [<ffffffff81731833>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526588]  [<ffffffff8106b97d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526594]  [<ffffffff8106b9ec>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526601]  [<ffffffff810a7934>] ? update_curr+0xe4/0x1b0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526610]  [<ffffffff81654926>] dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526617]  [<ffffffff816546b0>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526623]  [<ffffffff81078a06>] call_timer_fn+0x36/0x180
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526629]  [<ffffffff816546b0>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526635]  [<ffffffff81078fdc>] run_timer_softirq+0x22c/0x2e0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526642]  [<ffffffff81070f7c>] __do_softirq+0xfc/0x350
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526649]  [<ffffffff81071200>] run_ksoftirqd+0x30/0x70
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526655]  [<ffffffff81096da9>] smpboot_thread_fn+0x159/0x260
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526660]  [<ffffffff81735409>] ? schedule+0x29/0x70
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526665]  [<ffffffff81096c50>] ? SyS_setgroups+0x180/0x180
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526671]  [<ffffffff8108f8b9>] kthread+0xc9/0xe0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526682]  [<ffffffff8108f7f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526684]  [<ffffffff81740ba8>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526686]  [<ffffffff8108f7f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.526688] ---[ end trace 36eb59f55c077491 ]---
01/16/17 09:56:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37507.531429] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
01/16/17 09:57:03 AM    studionBitch    dbus[510]   [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
01/16/17 09:57:03 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [37567.951413] systemd-hostnamed[12395]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
01/16/17 09:57:03 AM    studionBitch    dbus[510]   [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
01/16/17 10:06:09 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [38113.056925] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
01/16/17 10:06:09 AM    studionBitch    whoopsie[1207]  offline
01/16/17 10:06:09 AM    studionBitch    whoopsie[1207]  online
01/16/17 10:16:15 AM    studionBitch    kernel  [38718.582492] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
01/16/17 10:16:15 AM    studionBitch    whoopsie[1207]  offline
01/16/17 10:16:15 AM    studionBitch    whoopsie[1207]  online
01/16/17 10:17:01 AM    studionBitch    CRON[13202] (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Any help interpenetrating all of this would be helpful.